# Discovery Client not initialized for Spring Health Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-check

I am trying to run a Spring boot application which is OpenAPI Generated. I have set the following configurations in my `application.yml`

```yaml
# Actuator Configuration

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: false
    refresh:
      enabled: false
    db:
      enabled: false
    diskspace:
      enabled: false
    vault:
      enabled: false      
health:
  config:
    enabled: false
```

But when I run the endpoint `/actuator/health`, I am getting the following response:

```
{
"description": "Discovery Client not initialized",
"status": "UNKNOWN"
}
```

NOTE:

**Spring Boot Version: 2.2.1.RELEASE**

Comment: Can you update to a more recent version? 2.2.1 is no longer supported. However checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939576/spring-actuator-service-discovery-health-descriptiondiscovery-client-no

Comment: Is there a PCF/Spring doc reference and you can share?

Comment: What reference do you mean?

Comment: Official documentation from the folks at Spring or Pivotal

Comment: https://spring.io/